# Eulerian Circuit algorithm

Tags: java, graph

This method draws an Eulerian Circuit from a directed graph. The graph is represented by an array of Deques representing outgoing edges. It does not have to be Deques if there is a more efficient data type; as far as I can tell the Deque is the most efficient implementation of a stack but I could be wrong.

I've tried replacing the `ArrayDeque`s with `LinkedList`s but it doesn't make any difference.

I've tried keeping an array edgeCount rather than checking the number of nodes using `edges[currentVertexNumber].size() > 0`. But that makes it slower.

```
import java.util.*;



class PrintCircuit{
    /**
     *
     * @param edges list of adjacent vertices for current edges
     * @return circuit in deque list
     */
    Deque<Integer> makeEulerianCircuit(Deque<Integer>[] edges, int numberOfNodes)
    {

        // return empty list for empty graph
        if (edges.length==0)
            return new LinkedList<>(); //empty graph

        // Stack for the path in the current iteration
        Deque<Integer> currentPath = new ArrayDeque<>();

        // queue for the final circuit
        Deque<Integer> circuit = new ArrayDeque<>();

        // start from any vertex
        currentPath.push(0);
        int currentVertexNumber = 0; // Current vertex

        while (!currentPath.isEmpty())
        {
            //if there are outgoing edges
            if (edges[currentVertexNumber].size() > 0)
            {
                currentPath.push(currentVertexNumber);
                int nextVertexNumber = edges[currentVertexNumber].pop();
                currentVertexNumber = nextVertexNumber;
            }

            // otherwise step back
            else
            {
                circuit.add(currentVertexNumber);
                currentVertexNumber = currentPath.pop();
            }
        }

        return circuit;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        PrintCircuit pc = new PrintCircuit();
        pc.inputAndPrintCircuit();

    }


    /**
     * Get the input, check to make sure the graph is even and run the printCircuit function
     */
    private void inputAndPrintCircuit(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] in = new int[2];
        in[0] = scanner.nextInt();
        in[1] = scanner.nextInt();
        Deque<Integer>[] edges = new Deque[in[0]];
        for(int i=0;i<in[0];i++)
        {
            edges[i] = new ArrayDeque<>();
        }

        // evenChecker is a Nx2 array where [0] = incoming edges and [1] = outgoing edges
        //should be equal or graph isn't Eulerian
        int[][] evenChecker = new int[in[0]][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < in[1]; i++) {
            int from = scanner.nextInt()-1;
            int to = scanner.nextInt()-1;
            evenChecker[from][0]++;
            evenChecker[to][1]++;
            edges[from].push(to);

        }
        if(!isGraphEven(evenChecker)){
            System.out.println("0");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("1");
        }
        Deque<Integer> circuit = makeEulerianCircuit(edges, in[0]);
        while(circuit.size()>1){
            int nextNode = circuit.pollLast()+1;
            System.out.print(nextNode + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    /**
     * checks to make sure that incoming edges = outgoing edges
     * @param evenChecker a Nx2 array where [0] = incoming edges and [1] = outgoing edges
     * @return true if incoming eges = outgoing edges, false otherwise
     */
    private boolean isGraphEven(int[][] evenChecker){
        for(int[] evenCheck:evenChecker){
            if(evenCheck[0]!=evenCheck[1]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }



}
```

Is there anything that can make this faster? Better data structures? A more efficient algorithm? Right now it's not passing the assignment I'm writing it for, and I can't think of anything to make it work more efficiently.

Update: 
Here are the specifications of the assignment:

> Task. Given a directed graph, find an Eulerian cycle in the graph or report that none exists.
>
> Input Format. The first line contains integers n and m — the number of vertices and the number of edges,
>   respectively. Each of the following m lines specifies an edge in the format “u v”. (As usual, we assume
>   that the vertices of the graph are {1, 2, . . . , n}.) The graph may contain self-loops (that is, edges of
>   the form (v, v)) and parallel edges (that is, several copies of the same edge). It is guaranteed that the
>   graph is strongly connected.
>
> Constraints. 1 ≤ n ≤ 104
>   ; n ≤ m ≤ 105
>   ; 1 ≤ u, v ≤ n.
>
> Output Format. If the graph has no Eulerian cycle, output 0. Otherwise output 1 in the first line and a
>   sequence v1, v2, . . . , vm of vertices in the second line. This sequence should traverse an Eulerian cycle
>   in the graph: (v1, v2),(v2, v3), . . . ,(vm−1, vm),(vm, v1) should all be edges of the graph and each edge of
>   the graph should appear in this sequence exactly once. As usual, the graph may contain many Eulerian
>   cycles (in particular, each Eulerian cycle may be traversed starting from any of its vertices). You may
>   output any one of them.

Here is some sample input:
Input:

> 3 4
>
> 2 3
>
> 2 2
>
> 1 2
>
> 3 1

Output:

> 1
>
> 1 2 2 3

I've also updated the above to include the entire program.

Comment: Why does this return an Eulerian circuit?  It seems like it just does a depth first search.

Comment: In what sense it doesn't pass the assignment?

Comment: `anything that can make this [… pass] the assignment` without a proper specification what the code is to achieve there is *no* way to improve it systematically. Where is the [javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide) for `makeEulerianCircuit()`? What *algorithm* are you trying to implement?

Comment: I've now included the whole program plus javadocs and the specifications of the assignment.

Comment: @vnp it does not pass the assignment because it's too slow. There are 47 tests; my program passes the first 40-43 before running over the expected time to pass.

Comment: Update: The instructors of my assignment said that the time requirements were unrealistic and have modified them; my assignment now passes the test. Thanks to everyone who responded. I recommend this question now be closed.

Comment: (Dang - I missed this comment. Then again, I *did* summarise my take on run time. (One up for instructors being open about own mistakes and correcting them!))

Comment: `recommend this question now be closed` So you think not only the question, but also existing *and upcoming* answers not useful regarding code&review? (Strictly, a reason to *down-vote* a post rather than delete or close it)

Comment: Okay never mind about closing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a *performance at the cost of readability* post, see [explicit praise for the comments, only](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/188800/93149) for a regular code review.
There *always* are "microefficiencies" one could worry about - and shouldn't, at least not until all bigger points are taken care of and a problem persists.
Still, it is advisable to start with emphasis on readability and improve the algorithm there.
One thing that might catch a would-be performance coder unawares is Java io performance - in particular, `java.util.Scanner` gets bashed. (I haven't tried to do useful measurements, I suspect it is comparatively bad only with big input files and no buffering.) For the hell of it:

```
/** Parses InputStream for smallish natural numbers: <code>char</code>s.
 * Skips non-digits; returns -1 - '0' on end-of-file */
class Chars { boolean hasCurrent; char current;
    final java.io.InputStream in;
    Chars() { this(System.in); }
    Chars(java.io.InputStream in) {
        this.in = in instanceof java.io.BufferedInputStream
            ? in : new java.io.BufferedInputStream(in);
    }
    /** @return current <code>char</code>. */
    public char current() {
        if (!hasCurrent)
            throw new RuntimeException("no current char");
        return current;
    }
    /** @return next <code>char</code>. */
    public char next() {
        try { int c, n = 0;
            while (!Character.isDigit(c = in.read()))
                if (-1 == c) // EOF
                    break; // throw? return 0?
            n = c - '0';
            while (Character.isDigit(c = in.read()))
                n = 10*n + c - '0';
            hasCurrent = true;
            return current = (char)n;
        } catch (IOException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
    }
}
```

Another point is memory occupancy at every level of the hierarchy. The `Constraints` read *no number exceeds 10<sup>5</sup>* - `short` or `char` should do fine instead of `int`.
 Instead of counting incoming and outgoing edges separately, keep balances (incremented for one, decremented for the other): graph not Eularian if any balance differs from zero after input.
 As a rule, instantiate "Java Collection Framework classes" using an expected size where possible. Here, no vertex will have more than *m-n* outgoing edges - but even instantiating *n* "Array-Collection"s with that size is Θ(n*m). *Not* specifying a capacity leads to Θ(mlogm) time if "almost all" edges are from one vertex.
 `java.util.LinkedList<E>` should be linear, but with high factors - for the hell of it:

```
/** Graph vertex keeping a <code>List</code> of successors.
 * (Only <code>add()</code> and <code>iterator()</code> are useful.) */
static class Vertex extends java.util.AbstractList<Vertex>
    implements java.util.Iterator<Vertex>//, List<Vertex> 
{
    Object label;
    static class Node {
        Node next;
        final Vertex v;
        public Node(Vertex v, Node next) {
            this.v = v;
            this.next = next;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringBuilder("N_").append(v.label).toString();
        }
    }
    Vertex.Node first;
//  static class Iterator implements java.util.Iterator<Vertex> {
        Vertex.Node next;
//      public Iterator(Vertex.Node first) { next = first; }
        public boolean hasNext() { return null != next; }
        public Vertex next() {
            Vertex current = next.v;
            next = next.next;
            return current;
        }
//  }

    public Vertex(Object label) { this.label = label; }
    static public final Vertex[]NONE = {};
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("V_").append(label).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Vertex v) {
        first = new Node(v, first);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<Vertex> iterator() {
        next = first;
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public Vertex get(int index) { return null; }
    @Override
    public int size() { return null == first ? 0 : 1; }
}
```

(There would be a way to use arrays, only - "FORTRAN", don't currently feel like coding that.)
Using above `Vertex` and an open coded stack:

```
/** @param vertices (index 0 shall not be used)
 * @param totalEdges total number of edges
 * @return circuit */
static Vertex[]
makeEulerianCircuit(Vertex[] vertices, int totalEdges) {
    if (vertices.length == 0) // empty graph
        return Vertex.NONE;
    // Stack for the path in the current iteration
    Vertex[] currentPath = new Vertex[totalEdges];//nVertices may be too low
    int top = -1;
    // final circuit
    Vertex[] circuit = new Vertex[totalEdges];
    int visit = circuit.length;
    // start from any vertex
    Vertex currentVertex = vertices[1];
    while (true) {//currentVertex.iterator()
        if (currentVertex.hasNext()) { // there is another outgoing edge
            currentPath[++top] = currentVertex;
            currentVertex = currentVertex.next();
        } else { // otherwise step back
            circuit[--visit] = currentVertex;
            currentVertex = currentPath[top--];
            if (top < 0)
                return circuit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you greybeard. Sorry for my cranky response from before. I appreciate all of your input and I learned some useful things from it. I especially didn't know that Scanner doesn't have good performance. I will mark this as the answer to the question, because it does seem like it would speed things up, though I probably won't actually do it because they changed the assignment required runtime so I passed anyway and I am completely sick of this program..

Answer (score 0):

(Usually, Eulerian circuits are considered for *un*directed finite graphs.)
The question is tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java) - while the *syntax* of the code presented looks the type, the variable handling looks Fortran.
`makeEulerianCircuit()` and `(inputAndPrintCircuit)` are instance members - needlessly. While it *may* be useful to have an abstraction *input&print*, having it print the result of a non-trivial algorithm looks odd. Specify and implement an `input()` method (and have that handle input using [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)).
`inputAndPrintCircuit()` shifts vertex numbers to differ from the problem statement - don't.
*Why* have an array `in[]` to hold input values that do have different meaning? Just use `nVertices` and `nEdges`. Similarly, consider using `nOutgoing[]` and `nIncoming[]` instead of a two-dimensional array. (Given a constant time `size()` for the collections of outgoing edges, you could do without `nOutgoing[]`.)
Much as I like code commented: `// empty graph` is redundant (I'd drop the comment before the conditional statement and let `// empty graph` comment the condition (slightly overstating the issue - a connected graph without edges still might contain one vertex; input spec: nVertices ≤ nEdges).)
You don't need `int nextVertexNumber` - assign `edges[currentVertexNumber].pop()` to `currentVertexNumber` directly.
I think `makeEulerianCircuit()` depends on `edges[]` specifying a (strongly) connected graph: its doc comment should reflect that.

An alternative design would introduce a `class Vertex`, each instance holding an assortment of other vertices that can be reached from this one.

Up to now, I didn't try and convince myself `makeEulerianCircuit()` does indeed put together an Eulerian circuit for each connected "even" graph - in part due to lack of a test scaffold in the question.

`Is there anything that can make this faster? Better data structures? A more efficient algorithm?`
I *think* this implements [Hierholzer's algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Hierholzer's_algorithm) in O(`m`) (with a bit of hand-waving around adding up to *m - n* edges to an `ArrayDeque` taking Θ(mlogm) time - with constants "never" allowing `LinkedList` to be faster). (If that was true, there *shouldn't* be a performance issue - I should *really* set up a test.)

Comment: First of all , thank you for responding. Just to be clear, except for the last sentence everything is a critique of my coding style, rather than an answer to the question I asked, and that your answer to the question that I asked is that you don't know? To answer your questions: it does return an eulerian circuit, in my tests and the assignment's tests; it's just too slow. You can see the test here: https://github.com/jimboweb/hierholzer3 . And the reason the coding style "looks like Fortran" is because I've stripped it to the bare minimum in an attempt to be fast enough to pass.

Comment: From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): ***Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?**    Feel free to call attention to specific areas you are concerned about (performance, formatting, etc). However, any aspect of the code posted is fair game for feedback and criticism.* [How do I write a good answer?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): *Every answer must make at least one insightful observation about the code in the question. … Answers need not cover every issue in every line of the code.*

Comment: Okay, sorry, I should have just listened to your ideas.